# How to force xml2js to output array for certain keys?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, xml, parsing

I have some XML which I want it to output into an array. But when only one item exists, [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) outputs the one item to an object. When there are multiple items, it outputs as an array. For consistency, how do I force it to be an array?

My XML looks like this:

```
const xml = `<Shift>
    <Transaction>
      <Currency>GBP</Currency>
      <Amount>24.50</Amount>
    </Transaction>
</Shift>`

parseStringPromise(xml).then(json => console.log(JSON.stringify(json)))
```

which as you can see outputs as:

```
{
  "Transaction": {
    "Currency": "GBP",
    "Amount": "24.50"
  }
}
```

But there are usually multiple transactions. So typically the XML will look like this:

```
const xml = `<Shift>
    <Transaction>
      <Currency>GBP</Currency>
      <Amount>24.50</Amount>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
      <Currency>GBP</Currency>
      <Amount>25.50</Amount>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
      <Currency>GBP</Currency>
      <Amount>26.50</Amount>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
      <Currency>GBP</Currency>
      <Amount>27.50</Amount>
    </Transaction>
</Shift>`

parseStringPromise(xml).then(json => console.log(JSON.stringify(json)))
```

which outputs into an array like so

```
{
  "Transaction": [
    {
      "Currency": "GBP",
      "Amount": "24.50"
    },
    {
      "Currency": "GBP",
      "Amount": "25.50"
    },
    {
      "Currency": "GBP",
      "Amount": "26.50"
    },
    {
      "Currency": "GBP",
      "Amount": "27.50"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I make sure that even when there is only 1 `Transaction` item in the xml, that it will output to an array?

Is there an option I need to pass to my parser or do I need to reformat my XML?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of XML to JSON converters out there and they all have this kind of problem. They do what you want in some cases, and not in others, and none of them offer much control. If you want control over the JSON that's produced I would recommend using XSLT 3.0: this allows you to transform the XML to correspond to the structure of the JSON you want to generate, before calling `xml-to-json()` to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [camaro](https://github.com/tuananh/camaro) for this purpose. camaro let you write a xpath-based template to specify how you want the output to be. in this case, you specify that you want an array out of it

```js
const { transform } = require('camaro')
const xml = `<Shift>
    <Transaction>
      <Currency>GBP</Currency>
      <Amount>24.50</Amount>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
      <Currency>GBP</Currency>
      <Amount>25.50</Amount>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
      <Currency>GBP</Currency>
      <Amount>26.50</Amount>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
      <Currency>GBP</Currency>
      <Amount>27.50</Amount>
    </Transaction>
</Shift>`

;(async function () {
    const template = {
        transactions: ['/Shift/Transaction', {
            Currency: 'Currency',
            Amount: 'Amount'
        }]
    }

    console.log(await transform(xml, template));

})()
```

output

```
{ transactions:
   [ { Currency: 'GBP', Amount: '24.50' },
     { Currency: 'GBP', Amount: '25.50' },
     { Currency: 'GBP', Amount: '26.50' },
     { Currency: 'GBP', Amount: '27.50' } ] }
```

even when there is only 1 element

```js
const { transform } = require('../')
const xml = `<Shift>
    <Transaction>
      <Currency>GBP</Currency>
      <Amount>24.50</Amount>
    </Transaction>
</Shift>`

;(async function () {
    const template = {
        transactions: ['/Shift/Transaction', {
            Currency: 'Currency',
            Amount: 'Amount'
        }]
    }

    console.log(await transform(xml, template));

})()
```

output

```
{ transactions: [ { Currency: 'GBP', Amount: '24.50' } ] }
```